# Css expand div with content but never shrink

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I wonder if it's possible to make div expand with text content but never shrink using CSS. Use case is that I've search bar in responsive modal, that gets resized back and forth, which is not a nice user experience. Also I've more use cases for this kind of thing. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post your CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/5cmsns2p/)
CSS:

```
div{
    width:90%;
    min-width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:moccasin;
}
```

It has a width of 90% but will never go below 500px.